# Getting GLib warning on passing struct as arg to G_CALLBACK

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to pass a pointer to struct as argument to callback function, but I'm getting this error

`(gtk:11156): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 22:34:21.308: invalid cast from 'GtkEntry' to 'GtkApplication'`

`(gtk:11156): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:34:21.308: gtk_application_window_new: assertion 'GTK_IS_APPLICATION (application)' failed`

when executing this code

```
Appnfile *argptr = (Appnfile*)data;
GtkWidget *window2 = gtk_application_window_new(GTK_APPLICATION(argptr->app1));  //this line has the error
```

Prototype of the callback function is

`static void second_win(GtkEntry *entry, gpointer data)`;

Declaration of struct and g_signal_connect line are

```
Appnfile arg;
arg.app1=app;
arg.buff=buffer;
g_signal_connect(name, "activate",G_CALLBACK(second_win),&arg);
```

Definition of struct is

```
typedef struct {
    GApplication *app1;
    GtkEntryBuffer *buff;
} Appnfile;
```

Link to the program is
[here](https://github.com/saturn660/stackoverflow/blob/master/prog_c/gtk_pr_a.c)

The code worked fine when I passed app as data on a g_signal_connect_swapped function. But on passing the same variable as a struct element I'm getting this warning.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one that includes the definition of `second_win`. Also please include the *full* and *complete* copy-pasted (as text) error output, and add comments on the lines in the code where the errors are. Lastly please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The `second_win` function is 53 lines long, and the other part of the function works fine.

Comment: @xing argptr->app1 has type GApplication, name has not been used in the entire function so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @xing I've added a github link to the program, please have a look.

Comment: 1) line 104: `arg` is allocated on stack, when this function returns it's not valid any more 2) what is "win2" signal?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I'm new to C and gtk. What should I do in its place, use malloc? "win2" is a new signal I thought of implementing, but that line is commented anyway.

Comment: @saturn660 mallocing is ok, but if you don't store that pointer anywhere, it will leak. I'd recommend reading a C book or something like that.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I know about the `free()` function, wouldn't using `free(ptr)` avoid the leak?

Comment: If you free it before function returns, it's undefined behavior. Read a book, memory management in C is not a trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander Dmitriev has it right. You're trying to use `arg` in `second_win`, but as `arg` is a struct allocated on the stack, as soon as you return from that function, it ceases to exists. There are two solutions to have `arg` live long enough:

- allocate it on the heap (with `malloc`, or `g_malloc`/`g_new`/`g_new0`)
- allocate it on the stack in a function you will return from only when `arg` is no more used

Here's a patch that uses the second solution. You may save it in `arg.patch` and apply it with `git am arg.patch`:

```
From 6c0679485cde31c55c58aa5f54f0a60d4c874d71 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Luis Menina <liberforce@freeside.fr>
Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 10:41:58 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] Create argument list where it will live long enough to be
 accessed

Declaring it on the stack inside a callback will make it be destroyed
when you exit the callback. By declaring it in the stack, in the main
you are sure that the structure has the same lifespan as your
application.
---
 prog_c/gtk_pr_a.c | 13 ++++++++-----
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

diff --git a/prog_c/gtk_pr_a.c b/prog_c/gtk_pr_a.c
index fb3b5a2..d11ba7d 100644
--- a/prog_c/gtk_pr_a.c
+++ b/prog_c/gtk_pr_a.c
@@ -80,6 +80,7 @@ static void first_win(GApplication *app, gpointer data){
     GObject *window, *name;
     GError *error =NULL;
     GtkEntryBuffer *buffer;
+    Appnfile *arg = data;

     builder= gtk_builder_new();
     if(gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "pr1.ui",&error)==0){
@@ -97,10 +98,9 @@ static void first_win(GApplication *app, gpointer data){
     gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));
     g_signal_connect( name, "activate", G_CALLBACK(search_user),buffer);

-    Appnfile arg;
-    arg.app1=app;
-    arg.buff=buffer;
-    g_signal_connect(name, "activate",G_CALLBACK(second_win),&arg);
+    arg->app1=app;
+    arg->buff=buffer;
+    g_signal_connect(name, "activate",G_CALLBACK(second_win), arg);
     g_signal_connect_swapped( name, "activate", G_CALLBACK(gtk_window_close),window);
     g_object_unref(window);
 }
@@ -117,7 +117,10 @@ static void first_win(GApplication *app, gpointer data){
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("org.my.app",
                         G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
-    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(first_win),NULL);
+    Appnfile arg;
+    memset(&arg, 0, sizeof(arg));
+
+    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(first_win), &arg);
     //g_signal_connect(app, "2win",G_CALLBACK(second_win),NULL);
     int status =g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app),argc, argv);
     g_object_unref(app);
-- 
2.17.1
```